# Does the Firebase Admin SDK read and writes count?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

it's a simple question. So When you write data to Firebase firestore using client side JavaScript code, Firebase counts that as a write and Firebase costs X amount of dollars for it and if you read the document in firestore using the client side JavaScript then that will also count, as a read and Firebase will charge X amount of dollars for that. Now what if Admin SDK reads a document? will that count as a read or if the Admin SDK writes, will that count as a write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reads and writes from/to Firestore with the Admin SDK count like Client SDKs reads and writes (and will be included in your monthly bill if the total number of reads/writes is over the free tier).

Note that this is also the case for reads and writes done through the Firebase console.

Comment: do you know whats the best way to store information logs, its better if I can access them through client or through admin SDK based on time they were logged.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "information logs"? And what influence the logging time would have?